# Add Navigation Arrows to Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, navigation

I'm looking to implement the following arrow design in my system where the arrow is on the selected item.
[image]

Currently I've implemented the menu as a ListBox and is behaving correctly, minus the arrow.
What's the best approach for implementing this sort of behaviour?

Currently, I have edited the ItemsControl and added an Arrow, but it is inside the border, instead of outside the border, like so:

[image]

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Border">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        </Border>
                        <Path Name="SelectedArrow" Data="{StaticResource RightArrow}" Width="10" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="SelectedArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override it's ItemTemplate to include an arrow and set its visibility on a trigger which can checks the condition of IsSelected.

Comment: I'm unsure of how to make the arrow 'outside' the ListBox. I've implemented the following in the ListBoxItem's ItemControl:
<code>
<Grid>
                        <Border Name="Border" Height="23" MinWidth="190">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Image Source="/Resources/Images/NavArrow.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </Grid>
</code>
I've tried to set the Margin, but it just made the Arrow disappear.